# How do I get more immediate word suggestions in Android 4.4 Kitkat?

Tags: keyboard, 4.4-kitkat, text-prediction

On my previous phone with the Android 2 stock keyboard, when typing, above the soft keys there was a list of word suggestions as long as the screen allowed.

In Android 4.4, there seems to be a maximum of 2 or 3. I know that you can press and hold one of the two suggestions on either side to get a few more, but this does not help speedy typing, as you may view these in vain, type a few more characters, try again, etc.

Does anybody know if/how I can get more suggestions to display *immediately* on the bar above the keyboard as the older Android versions helpfully did?

Comment: You can always install other keyboard apps from Playstore.

Comment: I may have to do that, but just find it hard to understand that Google would release such a regression, it would seem more likely I had missed a setting somewhere, they seem more hidden away under Android 4, there is a fear of text and menus, it seems.

Comment: "Smart" technology seems to involve an increasing reliance on the automation of these things i.e. they keyboard "should" predict everything right fist time. The execution of this... not so much to be honest. Your best bet is probably another Keybaord until Google update their one and maybe restore functionality. The first app I ever paid for was SwiftKey and I've never looked back, it just dwarfs the Google one. There's a 1 month free trial and that's worth a shot. It takes time to learn, but it is very good. Swype is great too as an alternative. Not ideal, but maybe easier.